# play! framework, define string in view markup

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm just starting to work with Play! 2.0 and I'm having trouble finding any good documentation or tutorials around the view markup. I had my "main" view defined as such:

```
@(title: Html, nav: String = "")(content: Html)
```

I'm not sure why the title param is/was Html, so I changed it to String. 
Now, in another view I had this:

```
@title = {
    Sign Up
}

@main(title, nav = "signup") { etc...}
```

I want to change the definition of title to a String so I changed that definition to:

```
@title = "My Title goes here"

@main(title, nav = "signup") { etc...}
```

But when I try that, I get the error: "not found: value title" when I refresh the page. How do I define strings here like the Html is defined? I realize I can just put the string in the call to main on that second line, BUT what I'm wondering here is just how to set @title the same way for a string as it was done for Html.

Also, anyone have a link to some good markup tutorials or documentation (the equivalent to [this for 2.0 would be great](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/templates))? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaTemplates Declaring reusable blocks

```
@title = @{"My Title goes here"}

@main(title) {etc...}
```

Comment: That's the page I needed to find... Thank you